# Trying to use Curve modifier to put a string of lights on a tree

Tags: bezier-curves

It's the staple of so many tutorials this time of year. I'm following some and mostly know what I'm doing. But *mostly* is the operative word.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out the Curve modifier. Sometimes it works perfectly. Other times (like now) it is an irritating failure. I have tried everything to get my array-of-lights-on-a-cord to follow the spiral curve found in the tree. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would love some pointers.

[Source Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ljwh3hycM100ZrWt4nwRQ57b94crqyr-/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Don't make your questions depend on downloading a file. Explain the issue you are encountering thoroughly, post some screenshots of your scene and settings. Questions are meant to be useful for future users, not just yourself

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- Put your object's origin at the same position as the curve's origin: Select the curve, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, select the object, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*.
- Give it enough *Count* in the *Array* modifier (or choose *Fit Curve* and select the curve)
- Choose the right *Deform* axis in the *Curve* modifier (here *Z* as it is the object local direction that is supposed to follow the curve)

[image]

Comment: Hello 'boots :). A little OT, but I just noticed you hit 50k, so congrats on that man :).

Comment: oh yes wow, well I spend a lot of time here  ;)

Comment: great pictures in your instagram by the way!!

Comment: Thanks, well I spend a lot of time there... :D

Comment: You are awesome, Moonboots! I often forget the little details which turn out to be So Huge when doing 3d anything. Thank you so much!

Comment: Follow-up: I thought I got it, but I cannot replicate this. The blend file is syncing so it can show you where I am. I have no idea how you have aligned those two; even when I match up the origins, I get a weird offset.

Comment: maybe share your file again

Comment: It's the same link; just updated.

Comment: You need to have both the 2 origins at the same position, I'm going to edit my answer to go in details

Comment: That's what I thought I did. Ugh. Thanks very much for your patience. Imma have a lie down.